# How to interpret a reported speech

Tags: backshifting

1. Ex 1) Direct speech: He said " We lived here for 5 years"
   Indirect speech : He told me that they had lived there for 5 years.

Ex 2) Direct speech: He said " We have lived here for 5 years"
Indirect speech: He told me that they had lived there for 5 years.

But how come I arrive at a conclusion when the indirect speech i.e, He said They had lived there for 5 years" does not specifically say whether they once lived there or the have been still living there? Could you pls help me how a context helps us to arrive at a conclusion on what exactly one is referring to( past simple or present perfect).

2. Indirect speech: She said she had to leave. when we convert it into a direct speech, which of these is correct and which of these is she referring to?
   a) she said " I have to go", or
   b) She said " I had to go".
3. Indirect speech: He said she had been writing when he had gone there. when we convert it into a direct speech,which of these is correct and which of these is he referring to?
   a) He said " she was writing when he went there", or
   b) He said " she had been writing when he went there".
4. Indirect speech: He said Everyday the train passed by while she was reading a newspaper. when we convert it into a direct speech,which of these is correct and which of these is he referring to?
   a) He said " Everyday, the train passed by while she was reading a newspaper ", or
   b) He said " Everyday, the train passes by while she is reading a newspaper "

Comment: Yes; an ambiguity is introduced. You'd have to rephrase, for instance _He told me that they had been living there for 5 years._ // 'Indirect speech' is a non-count compound noun in this sense: you say 'This is a sentence using indirect speech' not 'This is an indirect speech'.

Comment: OMG!!!  English can be ambiguous???  Say it isn't true!!!!

Comment: I find it odd that you would change *lived* or *have lived* to ***had*** *lived* and then ask about the meaning, when you're the one who's changed it. *He told me that they lived there for 5 years* and *he told me that they have lived there for 5 years* are the more literal translations. The use of ***had*** is an unnecessary change.